# Joining a Zoom meeting by SIP with Linphone

Tags: telephony, zoom

I noticed that Zoom invitations have a "join by SIP" part, so I duckduckwent SIP and got the impression that I could join a Zoom meeting with Linphone.  I created a SIP account, created a Zoom meeting on another computer, and dialed [meeting-id]@[given-ip] with Linphone.  But it didn't connect (stopped trying after a couple of seconds).  Have I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 1):

This used to work, to a degree.  You would dial in to an address like "1234567890@zoomcrc.com".  Recently (around May/June 2021), however, it has stopped working (Linphone simply freezes), and I haven't had a chance to debug it.

My packages and instructions are at https://github.com/bemoody/linphone-deb/ (and if anyone can help figure out why it no longer works, or how to make it work with newer versions of Linphone, that'd be cool. :))

**You needed to have support for H.264 and SRTP in Linphone.**  Since neither H.264 nor SRTP were available in the Debian packages of Linphone, I built my own modified packages.

**You also needed to *disable* Opus audio (otherwise you would get complete garbage).**  Zoom didn't support Speex, so you were stuck with uncompressed PCM or no audio at all.

The video quality was always poor, but it was nice that the bandwidth and CPU usage were low enough to work comfortably on an older laptop.

Audio was never completely reliable either; it seemed to randomly mute me after some time.  There are supposed to be ways to control the meeting (e.g. to mute/unmute yourself) using the number keys, and I could never make that work with Linphone either.

Answer (score 0):

https://linphone.org/ now also offers an AppImage for 64-Bit-Intel-Linux, which allows enabling H.264 and allows connecting to a Zoom conference, passcode could be entered using number keys or using the URL as indicated on https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/201363273-Using-the-SIP-H-323-Room-Connector. Sadly, the H.264 is downloaded via http and it seems there is no checksuming in place, i.e. you are running unsigned code on your system by doing this (see https://github.com/cisco/openh264/issues/3135 and https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/linphone-developers/2020-12/msg00030.html for reference).